# How to access column's row of csv file using PHP

Tags: php

i use this code and i got whole column value in that `$id` variable but i want to access only that 456 i.e i want to access row value of column. what can i do for it?[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeQtw.png)

The code i used is:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $c = 0;
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
    {
        $id=$filesop[0];
        $name = $filesop[1];
        $email = $filesop[2];

        $sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO csv (id, name, email) VALUES (?, ?,?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, 'sss', $id, $name, $email);
        $result=mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
        $c = $c + 1;
    }

        if($result){
            echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted ". $c ." recoreds";
        }else{
            echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
        }
```

Comment: With `if ($id == 456)`?

Comment: Unrelated issue but it deserves attention; Did you know `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated since `PHP 5.5` and they actually removed them in `PHP 7.0`? You should move over to the more secure and robust classes; [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) are the better alternatives to use. You should look into how to use the `->prepare` method of these classes! Rumor has it, every time a `mysql_*` function is called, a child drops his ice cream. Please think of the children.

Comment: are you sure about your comma delimiter ?

Comment: thank you for your great suggestion and i do as you said :) @IsThisJavascript

Comment: didn't work @u_mulder

Comment: It could be helpfull to post the source of you CSV-file. Did you mean you get the ful row instead of column?

Answer (score 1):

My csv looks like :

```
colA,colB,colC
456,person1,email1@example.com
896,person2,email2@example.com

<?php
$handle = fopen("example.csv", "r");

while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
{
    $id = $filesop[0];
    var_dump($id);
}
?>

Output : 
string(4) "colA" string(3) "456" string(3) "896"
```

If I use a wrong delimiter in fgetcsv (';' instead of ","):

```
output : 
456,person1,email1@example.com
```

If you want to add the row where id == 456 in your database :

```
while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
{
    $id = intval($filesop[0]);
    if($id == 456)
    {
         $name = $fileops[1];
         $email = $fileops[2];
         $sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO csv (id, name, email) VALUES (?, ?,?)");
        // i : integer (id)
        // s : string (name)
        // s : string (mail)
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, 'iss', $id, $name, $email);
        $result=mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: sir i got you but how can i use that string value in my program?? i want this if(id=456){ //do something}

Comment: You can parse the string to an integer value by: $your_integer_id = (int) $your_string_id;

Comment: After $id = $filesop[0]; you can do : if(intval($id) == 456){//doMethod();}

Comment: @ctbs1 how can i insert that first row into my database when if(intval($id==456) is satisfied??

Comment: I completed my first answer with an example to add the row where id == 456